# How to add a new server to anypoint studio, using a cloned server that had already a mule runtime installed

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-platform, anypoint-runtime-manager

To install a new server, our IT team cloned a previous server running Mule Runtime 4.

On the new server, I removed the previous connection to Anypoint by deleting both Mule agent files, the keystore, and the YML config file.

Then I ran the AMC setup provided by Anypoint Studio for the new server.

The new server came up online at Anypoint platform, but the original server became disconnected.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you delete the files from both Mule installations?

Comment: No, I only delete then in the new server.

Comment: Doing the same procedure on the original server solved the problem. Both live and kicking. Thanks for the tip.